# using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am having a heck of a time getting some data from a dom I want.

I have some html here:

```
 <ul id="userMenu">
      <li class="userGreet devi">I WANT THIS TEXT HERE </li><li> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more" title="Menu">Menu</a>
      <ul> ....
            <li class="home">   
            </li>
      </ul>
      ...</li>
 </ul>
```

I know if I say

```
var x = document.getElementById('userMenu');
```

I can get "something" back (though this is all in a portal so its incredibly difficult to put java script break points into this).  So I am not sure how I can go further to get the string `"I WANT THIS TEXT HERE "`  ?

I think I have to walk through childNodes but not sure how or what exactly I am getting back so I can get at that string, also getElementById didn't work for the class= would that be getElementByClass ?

New to this DOM stuff.

Comment: can you use jquery? or are you attempting to learn the dom?

Comment: ....that's why jQuery was invented. If you want to use jQuery, it is dead simple. The element is: $('#userMenu li').eq(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using plain javascript and making your code more robust if the order of elements changes a little bit, you could use both the id and the class to get it like this:

```
var text = document.getElementById('userMenu').getElementsByClassName("userGreet")[0].innerHTML;
```

or using tag names, it could be done like this:

```
var text = document.getElementById('userMenu').getElementsByTagName("li")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: that did it.  Probably pretty simple but this helped so much everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
var text = document.querySelectorAll('#userMenu li.userGreet.devi')[0].innerHTML;
```

See [MDN's documentation of querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll).

Note that this won't work on IE7. To do this kind of thing more easily in a cross-browser fashion, you can use one of the popular DOM manipulation libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

---

If your HTML is different from the text you want (i.e. you have markups for example), you might use this to get the interpreted text :

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('#userMenu li.userGreet.devi')[0];
var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;
```

Note that here again libraries help you deal with those incompatibilities between browsers. Jquery would let you do

```
var text = $('#userMenu li.userGreet.devi').text();
```

Comment: Use `textContent` (`innerText` for IE8) instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: The advantage of innerHTML is that it works for all browsers. As long as the text is the html, there is no worry.

Comment: textContent+innerText cover all browsers as well, *and* excludes HTML markup. The OP said "text", not "HTML". If the element contains HTML (elements / escaped entities), then the result is not "text".

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
document.getElementById('userMenu').children[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: Use `.children[0]` instead of `childNodes[0]` to make sure that text nodes are excluded.

Answer (score 1):

You can scan through like this

```
var x = document.getElementById('userMenu');  
var xChilds = x.childNodes;
var requiredElement = null;
for(var i = 0; i < xChilds.length; i++) {
   if(xChilds[i].className.indexOf('usergreet devi') !== -1) {
      requiredElement = xChilds[i];
      break;
   }
}

console.log(requireElement);
```

Comment: For modern browswer, use `querySelectorAll` as provided is dystroy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would make this easier.  You could do something like

```
var text = $('#userMenu .userGreet.devi').text();
```

Comment: The convention on SO is to not offer jQuery answers when jQuery is not specified.

Comment: jfriend00 - Sorry, didn't realize that - should I remove this answer?

Comment: I would love to use jquery as its me trying to cram some js into a portlet, I don't think it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is obvious, but... generally speaking, if you're going to be trying to access elements, give them IDs at the outset, it will save you lots of time.

```
<li id="ug0" class="userGreet devi">...</li>
```

Then of course

```
document.getElementById('ug0').innerHTML;
```